# Como crear un evento en C# para actualizar los datos de un datagridview con Mysql server

Tags: c#

Tengo un windows form y en una ventana tengo 3 Datagaridview cada uno se abre con un boton, en el primero calculo cuanta pintura se requiere para pintar ese objeto, al momento de darle clik al boton quiero que se quite del datagridview 1 y se mande al 2, pero no se hace, para que aparezca tengo que cerrar y abrir el programa nuevamente

Comment: Cuando doy click en el boton se sube a una bd en SQLServer, pero no me aparece en el datagridview 2

Comment: Y el codigo? como mostras y dejas de mostrar cada uno?